# Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: feature-selection, descriptive-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Back in Stackoverflow, I had asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374882/two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-python-scipy-on-brain-data) but was redirected here for clarifications related to statistics. As mentioned in the question, I have about 200 brain anatomical measurements from two groups of individuals and would like to extract the most distinguishing features. Can someone please suggest me which statistical tests are best to try.

Some papers mentioned the KS test. In the KS 2 sample test, I am confused if the 2 samples are a brain anatomical measurement (such as thickness of cortex) of two patients  one from each group? Or one patient from group 1 vs another patient from group 2 (taking all the different anatomical measurements at once)?

Comment: The purpose of the [two-sample KS test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) is to test whether two distinct, one-dimensional samples have the same distribution. It is not an explicit method for feature selection (although I suppose you can use the results from the test to do that). Without knowing anything more about your experiment, I'd say you're probably looking for the case where you have measurements from one group in sample 1 and the other in sample 2.

Comment: How many features ? 200 ? how many people in each  of two groups ?  what and why do you want to discriminate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2 sample test tests for the hypothesis that two **samples** share the same distribution, without specifying what that distribution is.

It does so by computing the difference between the empirical CDFs of both samples.

More info here: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/ks2samp.htm

The test wouldn't allow you to compare two patients, but rather to test for the hypothesis that the two groups of patients share the same distributions of brain measurements.